# Why is the Dictionary always new initialized?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've got a form and added a button ("add_source_button") to dynamically create new buttons on the form. These buttons are supposed to open a FileDialogue. This works so far, the window for the file selection is popping up correctly. I need to store the selected files in the "files" dictionary to have later access to the values. The issue is that the dictionary "files" always resets when I am adding a new file to the dictionary (probably cause it's calling the form when I am clicking on the add file selector button).

How do I have to adapt the code to store the selected files in the "files"-dictionary correctly?

Tried to define the files Dictionary in a seperate class, doesn't work

Form1

```
int counter = 0;
Dictionary<string, string> files = new Dictionary<string, string>();
utilitys Utility = new utilitys();

public Form1 ()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    datasource1_location = datasource1.Location;
    datasource1.Click += delegate { show_file_selector(datasource1.Name); };
}

private void add_source_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    counter++;
    datasource1_location.X += 50 + datasource1.Width;
    Utility.add_element_to_form(this, 50, 50, "datasource"+counter.ToString(), "blabla");
}

public void show_file_selector (string source)
{
    OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    fileDialog.Filter = "CSV-Files(*.csv)|*.csv";
    if (fileDialog.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
    {
        files.Add(source, fileDialog.FileName);
    }
}
```

Utility:

```
public void add_element_to_form(Form form, Size size, Point location, String control_name, String text)
{
    Form1 form1 = new Form1();
    Button new_source = new Button();
    new_source.Size = size;
    new_source.Location = location;
    new_source.Name = control_name;
    new_source.Text = text;
    new_source.Click += delegate { form1.show_file_selector(new_source.Name); };
    form.Controls.Add(new_source);
}
```

I am using `Form form` as I have different forms where I need to use that method.

Comment: You're passing in a reference to `Form1` to `add_element_to_form` as `form`, so you don't need `form1`.

Comment: How can I access the Form1.show_file_selector method then? If I am using form.show_file_selector it's not working, I need to get access to Form1 to have the ability to call the show_file_selector  method. Is there another way to call Form1.show_file_selector?

Comment: Well, the parameter is `Form form`, shouldn't that be `Form1 form`? Or do you need it for other forms?

Comment: Yes, I have different classes (and forms) where I have to call the add_element_to_form method.

Comment: Each Form1 instances you create will have their own individual dictionary instances. Putting stuff into the dictionary of one Form1 instance will obviously not make that stuff appear in the dictionary of another Form1 instance (in the same manner as putting stuff into the trunk of a car will not make the stuff materialize in the trunk of another car, irregardless of whether both cars are the same brand/model). There is nothing "resetting"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have different forms with the same method, the best you can do is add an interface to the forms where you need that method. Another way, assuming the implementation is always the same, which would make sense, is to extend the `Form` class by using another base class.

Here is a basic idea for the last approach:

```
public class FileSelectorBaseForm : Form
{
    protected Dictionary<string, string> Files = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    protected virtual void AddElementToForm(Size size, Point location, string controlName, string text)
    {
        Button newSource = new Button();
        newSource.Size = size;
        newSource.Location = location;
        newSource.Name = controlName;
        newSource.Text = text;
        newSource.Click += delegate { ShowFileSelector(newSource.Name); };
        Controls.Add(newSource);
    }

    protected virtual void ShowFileSelector(string source)
    {
        OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        fileDialog.Filter = "CSV-Files(*.csv)|*.csv";

        if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Files.Add(source, fileDialog.FileName);
        }
    }
}
```

You would then use this for Form1:

```
public class Form1 : FileSelectorBaseForm
```

Notice that I have fixed the names of the elements to follow c# conventions.